# How to implement custom traits in Objective-C?

Tags: swift, objective-c, uikit, uitraitcollection

The WWDC 2023 video [Unleash the UIKit trait system](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10057) discusses new UIKit APIs added in iOS 17 related to custom traits in trait collections. The video and its associated code is all in Swift but I wish to use these APIs in an older Objective-C app. I've run into some questions while converting the sample code from Swift to Objective-C.

To start, here is some sample Swift code provided on the Code tab (at timestamp 11:00) of the video:

```swift
enum MyAppTheme: Int {
    case standard, pastel, bold, monochrome
}

struct MyAppThemeTrait: UITraitDefinition {
    static let defaultValue = MyAppTheme.standard
    static let affectsColorAppearance = true
    static let name = "Theme"
    static let identifier = "com.myapp.theme"
}

extension UITraitCollection {
    var myAppTheme: MyAppTheme { self[MyAppThemeTrait.self] }
}

extension UIMutableTraits {
    var myAppTheme: MyAppTheme {
        get { self[MyAppThemeTrait.self] }
        set { self[MyAppThemeTrait.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

So far, this is what I have for the Objective-C conversion:

*MyTraits.h*:

```objc
@import UIKit;

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    MyAppThemeStandard,
    MyAppThemePastel,
    MyAppThemeBold,
    MyAppThemeMonochrome
} MyAppTheme;

@interface MyAppThemeTrait : NSObject<UINSIntegerTraitDefinition>

@end

@interface UITraitCollection (MyTraits)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyAppTheme myAppTheme;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

*MyTraits.m*:

```objc
#import "Traits.h"

@implementation MyAppThemeTrait

+ (NSInteger)defaultValue { return MyAppThemeStandard; }

+ (BOOL)affectsColorAppearance { return YES; }

+ (NSString *)name { return @"Theme"; }

+ (NSString *)identifier { return @"com.myapp.theme"; }

@end

@implementation UITraitCollection (MyTraits)

- (MyAppTheme)myAppTheme {
    return [self valueForNSIntegerTrait:MyAppThemeTrait.class];
}

@end
```

The sticky point here is how to implement the extension on the `UIMutableTraits` protocol. Objective-C doesn't support adding a computed property to a protocol through an extension/category. How do you finish implementing custom traits in Objective-C when the language doesn't support what is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you don't need the computed property on `UIMutableTraits` for this to work. That added property in the example Swift code is just a convenience for later use. In Objective-C, you can still make it work, it's just that the final code is slightly more cumbersome.

For example, in the Swift code you can create a `UITraitCollection` with the sample custom trait using code such as:

```swift
let myTraits = UITraitCollection { mutableTraits in
    mutableTraits.myAppTheme = .pastel // <-- custom trait here
    mutableTraits.horizontalSizeClass = .regular
}
```

In Objective-C, the code looks as follows:

```objc
UITraitCollection *myTraits = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraits:^(id<UIMutableTraits>  _Nonnull mutableTraits) {
    [mutableTraits setNSIntegerValue:MyAppThemePastel forTrait:MyAppThemeTrait.class];
    mutableTraits.horizontalSizeClass = UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular;
}];
```

Since there is no convenience property named `myAppTheme` on `UIMutableTraits`, we need to use the more verbose syntax of calling `setNSIntegerValue:forTrait:` (or `setObjectValue:forTrait:` or `setCGFloatValue:forTrait:` as needed for the given trait).

However, there is the added property `myAppTheme` on `UITraitCollection` so we can now read the value as follows:

```objc
MyAppTheme theme = myTraits.myAppTheme;
```

To see a fully working example in Objective-C, create a new iOS app project. Select Storyboard for the user interface and Objective-C for the language.

Add MyTraits.h and MyTraits.m as shown in the question above.

To work with the theme, we need to add a custom dynamic color. Add the following to *MyTraits.h*:

```objc
@interface UIColor (MyTraits)

@property (nonatomic, readonly, class) UIColor *customBackgroundColor;

@end
```

Add the following to *MyTraits.m*:

```objc
@implementation UIColor (MyTraits)

+ (UIColor *)customBackgroundColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithDynamicProvider:^UIColor * _Nonnull(UITraitCollection * _Nonnull traitCollection) {
        // This example uses some randomly chosen colors. Pick your own to suit your needs
        switch (traitCollection.myAppTheme) {
            case MyAppThemeStandard:
                return [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1];
            case MyAppThemePastel:
                return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.39 green:0.58 blue:0.93 alpha:1];
            case MyAppThemeBold:
                return [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1];
            case MyAppThemeMonochrome:
                return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.3 alpha:1];
            default: // make the compiler happy
                return UIColor.systemBackgroundColor; // This shouldn't happen
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

In *ViewController.m*, add the following code to `viewDidLoad`. This creates a button that overrides the `myAppTheme` trait with a random theme.

```objc
// Let's see when the theme changes
[self registerForTraitChanges:@[ MyAppThemeTrait.class ] withHandler:^(__kindof id<UITraitEnvironment>  _Nonnull traitEnvironment, UITraitCollection * _Nonnull previousCollection) {
    NSLog(@"VC change myAppTheme: %ld", traitEnvironment.traitCollection.myAppTheme);
}];

// Set the background to the custom theme color
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundColor;

// Setup a button to randomly change the theme
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
UIButtonConfiguration *cfg = [UIButtonConfiguration grayButtonConfiguration];
cfg.title = @"Change";
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithConfiguration:cfg primaryAction:[UIAction actionWithHandler:^(__kindof UIAction * _Nonnull action) {
    NSInteger theme = arc4random() % 4; // Pick a random theme
    // Set the new theme
    [weakSelf.traitOverrides setNSIntegerValue:theme forTrait:MyAppThemeTrait.class];
    // If we could add the convenience property to UIMutableTrait then this line would simply be:
    // weakSelf.traitOverrides.myAppTheme = theme;
}]];
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:btn];

// Put the button in the center of the screen
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [btn.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],
    [btn.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor],
]];
```

Build and run the app. Each time you tap the button the view controller's background color will change depending on the random theme that gets selected. You will also see a log message in the console showing what theme has been selected.

Comment: Instructive and entertaining.